# Dynamic OLAPCube Flex

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, olap, olap-cube

I'm trying to push data into an OLAPCube in flex.  The data coming in is flat and nothing else is known before hand.
How do I have flex automatically create dimensions and such so that I can bind something to the cube?  Using a flex chart, it's as simple as setting the data provider to an array collection and it works.

The ONLY examples I have come across show how to hard-code names of data using flex; nothing dynamic.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's several months since I attempted this but I found a lot of useful links on this page:

http://flexpearls.blogspot.com/2008/04/using-flex-olapolapdatagrid-for-doing.html

The pivotComponent does a lot on the fly.

Comment: As a disclaimer I should add that we didn't end up using Flex's OLAP components at all... so good luck with that :)